# Gorge on Vs binge on Vs devour

Tags: vocabulary

I've looked up the definition of "gorge on" in Lexico dictionary and it says "eat a large amount greedily". But I don't quite get it. How is it different from "binge on" and "devour". Could you please give me some examples and situations in which the use is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

To **gorge on** something is eating a lot of it at high speed. Gorging on something gives the image of stuffing your face so much that your cheeks or belly are bulging out and you keep stuffing more in. Compare with the word "engorged", which means full to bursting. "Power eating" competitions are all about gorging.

To **binge on** something is to continue to eat it over an extended period of time. Eating a large bag of potato chips at a normal pace, but all in one sitting, is an example. We "binge on" Netflix, not "gorge on" Netflix because it's about how long we do it, not how fast we watch.

To **devour** something means to eat it quickly and entirely. The amount of food doesn't matter. For example, if you're hungry and pressed for time at lunch, you might devour a sandwich. It also applies to really delicious things, like if you bake great cookies, when your friends come over, they devour them, i.e., they're all gone fast.

Answer (score 0):

gorge on and binge on are basically the same thing. To eat too much of some food(s).

devour [direct object] means to eat one thing in its entirety or completely.

- He devoured his meal
- Some insects gorge on blood. [formal]
- The kids binged on chocolate. [slangy]

Binge is more slangy.